# Run-time error '1004': Application defined or object-defined error - filter couple of pivot table by date

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

So I'm trying to filter the same date of a couple of pivot tables.
It works to the first pivot table, but then the others 5, gives the error of "run-time error 1004..."

They're 6 pivot tables that has the same data base.
And the code is in module form of the workbook.

Code below:

```
Sub filter()

Windows("SAFE.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Dinamic").Activate

Dim Datainicial As String
Dim Datafinal As String

Datainicial = Range("A2").Text
Datafinal = Range("C2").Text

If Range("A2").Text = "" Or Range("C2").Text = "" Then

MsgBox "Veuillez sélectionner la période souhaitée pour l'analyse.", vbCritical, "Date d'insertion"
Exit Sub
End If


Dim Tabela1 As PivotTable
Dim Tabela2 As PivotTable
Dim Tabela3 As PivotTable
Dim Tabela4 As PivotTable
Dim Tabela5 As PivotTable
Dim Tabela6 As PivotTable

Set Tabela1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Dist")
Set Tabela2 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Protection")
Set Tabela3 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IGtraité")
Set Tabela4 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PIMOF")
Set Tabela5 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IGencours")
Set Tabela6 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("IGouvert")

'Tabela1 - Distribuição afetação TOP 5
Tabela1.ClearAllFilters
Tabela1.PivotFields("Code NITG").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionDoesNotContain, Value1:="(em branco)"
Tabela1.PivotFields("Dernière source intégrée").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="DRG"
 Range("T7").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Dist").PivotFields("Libellé NITG").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Quantité", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Dist").PivotColumnAxis. _
        PivotLines(1), 1
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Dist").PivotFields("Code NITG").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Dist").PivotFields("Code NITG").PivotFilters.Add2 _
        Type:=xlTopCount, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Dist").PivotFields( _
        "Quantité"), Value1:=5
Tabela1.PivotFields("Date d'insertion").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Datainicial, Value2:=Datafinal


'Tabela4 - PIMOF
Tabela4.PivotFields("Date d'insertion").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Datainicial, Value2:=Datafinal

'Tabela5 - IG en cours
Tabela5.PivotFields("Date d'insertion").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Datainicial, Value2:=Datafinal

'Tabela6 - IG ouverts
Tabela6.PivotFields("Date d'insertion").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Datainicial, Value2:=Datafinal


'Tabela3 - IG traité
Tabela3.PivotFields("Date d'insertion").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Datainicial, Value2:=Datafinal

MsgBox "Période d'analyse souhaitée définie."

End Sub
```

Comment: Table1 you clear the filters first `Tabela1.ClearAllFilters` before adding the filter. The other tables you don't.

Comment: Thank you @CDP1802, but I can't clerar all of them, because they're grouped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the existing filter before adding the new one.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub filter()

    Windows("SAFE.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Dinamic").Activate
    
    Dim Datainicial As String, Datafinal As String
    Datainicial = Range("A2").Text
    Datafinal = Range("C2").Text
    
    If Range("A2").Text = "" Or Range("C2").Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Veuillez sélectionner la période souhaitée pour l'analyse.", vbCritical, "Date d'insertion"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Tabel As PivotTable, ar, tbl
    ar = Array("Dist", "Protection", "IGtraité", "PIMOF", "IGencours", "IGouvert")
    For Each tbl In ar
       Set Tabel = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tbl)
       With Tabel
           If tbl = "Dist" Then
               .ClearAllFilters
               .PivotFields("Code NITG").PivotFilters.Add _
                    Type:=xlCaptionDoesNotContain, Value1:="(em branco)"
    
               .PivotFields("Dernière source intégrée").PivotFilters.Add _
                    Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="DRG"
    
               .PivotFields("Libellé NITG").AutoSort xlDescending, "Quantité", _
                    .PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1

               .PivotFields("Code NITG").PivotFilters.add2 _
                    Type:=xlTopCount, DataField:=.PivotFields("Quantité"), Value1:=5
            Else
                .PivotFields("Date d'insertion").ClearAllFilters
            End If
            .PivotFields("Date d'insertion").PivotFilters.Add _
                Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Datainicial, Value2:=Datafinal
       End With
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Période d'analyse souhaitée définie."

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @CDP1802, but I can't clerar all of them, because they're grouped..

Comment: @Tatiana Yes my code only clears all filters on `Dist` the others it only clears `Date d'insertion`

Comment: it worked. Thank you!